# Flutter giving No known class method for selector 'appleCredentialWithIDToken:rawNonce:fullName:'

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I updated my flutter project's following two dependencies:

1. firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
2. firebase_core: ^2.9.0

And since then whenever I try to launch the project I get

```
ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No known class method for selector 'appleCredentialWithIDToken:rawNonce:fullName:'
/Users/saadbashir/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-4.4.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:592:26
```

Following are the dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
  firebase_core: ^2.9.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.1
  form_field_validator: ^1.1.0
  lottie: ^2.2.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.6+1
  path_provider: ^2.0.12
  image_cropper: ^3.0.1
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
  provider: ^6.0.5
  http: ^0.13.5
  animate_do: ^3.0.2
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  google_mlkit_face_detection: 0.5.0
  google_mlkit_text_recognition: 0.5.0
  camera: ^0.10.3+2
  image: ^4.0.12
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.3
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  location: ^4.4.0
  google_maps_flutter: 
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.19
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  basic_utils: 5.5.3
  time_range: ^1.0.3
  jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  flutter_background_service: ^2.4.6
  flutter_background_service_ios: ^2.4.0
  flutter_background_service_android: ^3.0.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.20
  barcode_widget: ^2.0.3
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  socket_io_client: ^2.0.1
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

Comment: Care to share you pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: @tomerpacific assuming you wanted to look at other dependencies, I have updated the question.

Comment: @SaadBashir did you ever figure it out? I have the exact same problem. (The answer about updating the FirebaseFirestore in the Pod file did not help)

Comment: @MagnusJohansson nope still stuck. That didn't work for me either.

Comment: Ok, it works for me now. I did 2 things; 
1) Updated the target iOS version to 16.0, the minimum deployment version to 13.0 (was 12.0 for me). And 
2) I ran the command `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` 

(Also did , as per usual: 
cd into ios folder
rm -rf Pods
delete Podfile.lock and run:
pod install --repo-update)

Comment: It worked for me. I added the following line in my Podfile $FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.7.0' apart from the steps you suggested. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept the answer, as it maybe helpful for other members of the community facing the same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, updated ios_firebase_sdk to the latest.

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.7.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by removing the caret symbol ^ from pubspec.yaml

Instead of `dependencies: firebase_auth: ^4.3.0`, use `dependencies: firebase_auth: 4.3.0`. And then run `flutter pub get`